# Django piston message encode problem

Tags: django, django-piston

I have a project on Django 1.3 + piston for API.
This is the code of GET handler:

```
listen_resource = Resource( ListenHandler )

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
  url( r'^listen/(?P<expression>.*)$', listen_resource ),
)


class ListenHandler(BaseHandler):   
    def read( self, request, expression ):            

        retval = {}
        print expression

        try:
            j_data = simplejson.loads(expression) 

    ...
```

The Get request usually is a JSON formatted string like this:

```
/api/listen/%7B%22act%22:%221%22,%22login%22:%22Terminal_001%22,%22passw%22:%2211223344%22,%22body%22:%22%7B%5C%22date%5C%22:%5C%222011-09-14%2016:34:26%5C%22,%5C%22link%5C%22:%5C%220%5C%22%7D%22%7D
```

when I print it:

```
print expression
```

while running project by Eclipse IDE on development server, the result is :

```
{"act":"1","login":"Terminal_001","passw":"11223344","body":"{\"date\":\"2011-09-13 16:59:31\",\"link\":\"0\"}"}
```

and I can create object from this Json formatted string:

```
j_data = simplejson.loads(expression)
```

But while running project on Apache server + mod_wsgi, the result is :

```
{"act":"1","login":"Terminal_001","passw":"11223344","body":"{/"date/":/"2011-09-13 17:46:42/",/"link/":/"0/"}"}
```

the Backslashes are replaced by slash and operation `simplejson.loads(expression)` is raising exception :

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
('Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 64 (char 64)',)
```

In Apache server conf file I added this line `AllowEncodedSlashes On`

please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating apache, problem was in this bug 
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256